# How to release WP8 Cordova app?

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, release

I've developed an app for Windows Phone 8 based on `cordova-cli`. What are the steps required to

- create a release bundle from the Cordova based app? `cordova build wp8 --release` or is there anything else to do, like signing the bundle?
- how and where to I release the app? (I already own a Windows Phone Developer account.)

Comment: no there is not any singing bundle in you bin->release-> .xap file is final release build  and one more you app package name must unique.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am somewhat damaged by the complicated processes on Apple iOS platform with all that signing and profiles required for release/testing on iPhone devices. Can you rewrite your comment as an answer?

Comment: yes wait i will give you full answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Windows Phone Developemt you do't need any provisioning profile like `ios` or keystore like `android`.

Open this Link for publich app  market store :  https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/publish#2

->First step Image show to on Click Upload Icon

[image]

Open this Link for publich app  market store :  https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/publish#2

->Login with microsoft Account thats must done payment for windows phone developemt.

->After login you can see one Submit app page it show in image and click on App Info

[image]

->In App info click you see all information you need to enter releated to app name, category, priceing, or you want to release beta version for testing.

[image]

->On Save click you get one Screen with you App Name with another option Upload and describe your project

->Click uplaod to you see on Add button to upload .Xap on for bin->release->appname.xap

->after you continue to view one page related to App icon Size, screenshot size, app description, version ects.

-> than Save your app and wait for approve proccess.

[image]